# Is it ok to post the same question to two different StackExchange sites, for ex Math/Physics?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, cross-posting

I asked this question: [What are "instantaneous" rates of change, really?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321769/what-are-instantaneous-rates-of-change-really/1321918#1321918) on Math.SE.

I got very interesting answers from different perspectives, which to me is one of the greatest values of these sites.

It seems to me that mathematicians and physicists have a generally different approach to mathematics, especially (in my experience) when it comes to intuition about infinity and calculus concepts.

So I was thinking about posting the exact same question on Physics.SE to get Physicists' perspective on it, which I'm sure would be different and also very interesting.

Would this be fine?

**EDIT**: Someone did post a more "physicist view" answer to my question, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the specialty bounderies of both sites in the sense that most people on one are also on the other, I'm not sure.

Comment: If you do it, be sure to leave a link to each question at the other question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, good point thanks, will do.

Comment: Note that we generally close questions on [physics.SE] which we discover to be cross-posted to other SE sites.