# How long should one wait before cross-posting?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, mathoverflow, cross-posting

In posting questions on MSE, I find that, if a question is not answered within a day or so, it will not receive an answer at all. Typically, I have waited for several weeks before cross-posting such a question on MathOverflow, where usually it gets a good response. From my experience, however, there seems to be no point in waiting so long, and a wait of one week is plenty to confirm that a question will not be answered.

I normally post a question on MSE first because I expect or hope that it will get an answer here. Sometimes it turns out that a question is more suited to MO, but generally I can't tell this in advance—perhaps there is a ready answer that I missed, and I don't want to bother the MO forum with off-topic material.

Thus, to formulate a specific question: Is it is considered acceptable behaviour to post on MO a question that received no answer on MSE within a week? If not, what would be deemed an appropriate waiting period?

Comment: I have added the ([meta-tag:cross-posting]) tag. Since you're interested mainly in MO, maybe ([meta-tag:mathoverflow]) could be added as well. Using those tag, you can check some older discussions related to this topic, if you check the questions tagged [meta-tag:cross-posting] or [cross-posting+mathoverflow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting+mathoverflow).

Comment: You might have a look at some posts on this on MathOverflow Meta, such as: [Cross posts to Math SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2637#2638). And also on this meta: [Asking the same question on MSE and MO](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16288). (Some of the [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/16288) might be of interest, too.)

Comment: I recommend a week, during normal (non pandemic) times.  Then those who read math.se only once a week have a chance to answer.  Of course your question must have good tags, so our hypothetical reader will see it even if it is not on the "recent" page.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to the helpful links posted in the comments by Martin Sleziak, I obtained a precise answer to the question [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638). The answer, on MO Meta, was to a question about cross-posting in the opposite direction, but it explicitly dealt with both directions.

The answer, which was the sole answer to the question and by a high-rep poster, was well upvoted and accepted. In short, it said that one week is fine, and I will take that advice.

Answer (score -4):

Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  See the general rules on Meta.SE: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

These rules are the default for Stack Exchange sites.  Individual SE sites can set a local policy that overrides that default, if they wish.  If *both* sites allow cross-posting, then you may cross-post as long as you comply with *both* sites' rules. Otherwise, do not cross-post your question on multiple sites -- no matter how long you wait.

Math.SE's policy appears to be documented here: [Is cross-posted forbidden/discouraged on Stack Exchange sites? If so, why?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9337/14578) and [Is cross-posting the same question to multiple sites not allowed when it is on-topic everywhere?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21237/14578) and [Asking the same question on MSE and MO](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16288/14578).  Before cross-posting on another site, please make sure you find their policy on their Meta.  If you can't find a specific policy on their Meta that allows cross-posting, then do not cross-post; the general default SE policy applies, and cross-posting is forbidden.